# BroadcastReceiver not called when set via AlarmManager in UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, unhandled-exception

I am setting an `Intent` for a `BroadcastReceiver` during an uncaught exception, using a `PendingIntent` and `AlarmManager`, as shown in the code below. On my Android 7.0 device, this code is working. On earlier devices, the `BroadcastReceiver` is never invoked. Why not?

My `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`, member of an `Application` subclass:

```
public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
{
  Intent restartIntent = new Intent (getApplicationContext (), RestartReceiver.class);

  PendingIntent pendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast (getApplicationContext (), 0, restartIntent, 0);

  AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarm.set (AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis () + 5000, pendingIntent);

  System.exit (1);
}
```

The receiver:

```
public class RestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    Intent restartIntent = new Intent (context, RestartActivity.class);
    context.startActivity (restartIntent);
  }
}
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.perinote.crashtest"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <application
    ...
    <receiver
      android:name=".RestartReceiver"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: > try this one [BroadCasting through Alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204387/alarmmanager-setinexactrepeating-setwindow-setrepeating-methods-do-not-fire-al/44205413#44205413)

Comment: I don't see the problem but I use in my app this code and works:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Utils.VERSION_KIT_KAT) {
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, alarm.getNextTimeMillis() - 10000, pi);
            } else {
                am.setWindow(AlarmManager.RTC, (alarm.getNextTimeMillis() - 10000), 10000, pi); 
            }