# Create notification with SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, notifications, android-sqlite

I am trying to develop an app, but I faced to a problem...
In my app I have a database with some data like hour and minute and some other stuff, I want to create a notification for time columns.

I created notification with these code:

```
public void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int hour, int minute) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getContext().getApplicationContext(), TaskReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(TaskReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(TaskReceiver.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext().getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}

private Notification getNotification(String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setContentTitle("Text Title");
    builder.setContentText("Some Text");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000});

    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 1, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    return builder.build();
}
```

and call it in activity like:

```
Cursor c = dbManager.fetch();
    if(c != null){
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            int hour = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CLOCK_HOUR));
            int minute = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.CLOCK_MINUTE));

            scheduleNotification(getNotification("Test"), hour, minute);
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cursor is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But it is not working, can anyone help me?

Comment: try this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204387/alarmmanager-setinexactrepeating-setwindow-setrepeating-methods-do-not-fire-al/44205413#44205413

Comment: @AniruddhParihar It does not work for me, because when I read data from database and set them for notification, notification does not show. I don`t know why.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you see an error message, have you tried any debugging? If yes, what were the results?

Comment: @PPartisan Yes I did everything, I mean the notification just shows up for last item in my listView. I cannot access to all records in my DB

Comment: "I cannot access to all records in my DB" - You mean your Database isn't returning the expected number of rows?

Comment: @PPartisan No, Imagine we have some records in DB like: 13:45, 14:20, 3:05. When I use scheduleNotification Method, the notification just shows up for the last one (in this case 3:05) not the others

Comment: My guess is it's related to your `PendingIntent` inside `getNotification()` not having unique IDs. Try using something unique, like the `_id` column from your database, instead of just setting it to `1`

Comment: @PPartisan Thanks for your fast response, OK I will try this way and let you know. Merci...

Comment: @PPartisan it`s work, thanks a lot. I owe you a coffee... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, as PPartisan mentioned above, the problem was PendingIntent.
So I change scheduleNotification method and now it`s working fine:
scheduleNotificaion method:

```
public void scheduleNotification(int hour , int minute){
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(500) + 20;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int curHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int curMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    int subHour = hour - curHour;
    int subMinute = minute - curMinute;

    if(subHour < 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm hour Passed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(subMinute < 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm minute passed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), randomNumber, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + subHour * 60 * 60 * 1000 + subMinute * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

and in onCreate method:

```
if (listView.getAdapter().getCount() != 0){
        emptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int hour = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.HOUR));
        int minute = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.MINUTE));
        scheduleNotification(hour, minute);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int hourNext = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.HOUR));
            int minuteNext = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.MINUTE));
            scheduleNotification(hourNext, minuteNext);
        }
    } else {
        //what ever
    }
```

This is just simple changes to make myself understand the way...
Thanks to PPartisan...

Comment: Glad my solution helped, but just FYI, your current system for generating unique IDs doesn't guarantee your IDs are in fact unique. Using the value stored in the `_id` column of your SQLiteDatabase would be quite robust. Or, you can create a central counter that uses an `AtomicInteger` (See the source code for `View#generateViewId` or an idea on how to do this)...although this wouldn't survive app relaunches.